# Does same design work for phone as well as tablet while developing app in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in phonegap and right now searching about design issues for tablets and phone.
Does the same design work for both phone as well as tablets?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your design "Responsive" .

Responsive Web design (RWD) is a Web design approach aimed at crafting sites to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a wide range of devices (from mobile phones to desktop computer monitors).

A site designed with RWD adapts the layout to the viewing environment by using fluid, proportion-based grids, flexible images, and CSS3 media queries, an extension of the @media rule.

See More : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about responsiveness. If you don't already know there are a couple of frontend frameworks for responsive web design.

One of them (and mostly used) is [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Some googling about "Bootstrap and phonegap" would provide a good knowledge.

[This artical](http://mobidev.biz/blog/phonegap%3a_how_to_create_one_app_for_all_platforms.html)  would be a good starting point as well.